# Perl reading only specific gz file lines

Tags: perl, gzip, tie

I'm trying to make a parsing script that parses a huge text file (2 million+ lines) that is gunzip compressed. I only want to parse a range of lines in the text file. So far I've used zgrep -n to find the two lines that mentions the string that I know will start and end the section of the file I'm interested.

In my test case file I am interested in only reading in lines 123080 to 139361. I've found Tie::File to access the file lines using the array object it returns, but unfortunately this won't work for the gun zipped file I'm working with.

Is there something like the following for a gunzipped file?

```
use Tie::File
tie @fileLinesArray, 'Tie::File', "hugeFile.txt.gz"
my $startLine = 123080;

my $endLine = 139361;    
my $lineCount = $startLine;
while ($lineCount <= $endLine){
    my $line = @fileLinesArray[$lineCount]
    blah blah...
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [IO::Uncompress::Gunzip](http://p3rl.org/IO::Uncompress::Gunzip) which is a core module:

```
use IO::Uncompress::Gunzip;

my $z = IO::Uncompress::Gunzip->new('file.gz');
$z->getline for 1 .. $start_line - 1;
for ($start_line .. $end_line) {
    my $line = $z->getline;
    ...
}
```

[Tie::File](http://p3rl.org/Tie::File) gets very slow and memory hungry when processing large files.

Comment: Thank you for the quick response! Is there a way to jump directly to the start line without have to perform a getline for the first couple of thousand lines? Run time for the first lines up until the start_line was something I was trying to avoid.

Comment: If the lines are a fixed length, you can `seek` to the correct record (`$z->seek($record_length * $start_line, 0)`)

Comment: Thanks @mob. When you used $record_length do you mean you need to multiply the number of total lines within the file by the start line? 

Looking at the documentation for seek it says we need ($positon,$whence). In this case wouldn't it be seek($start_line,0)?

Meaning that we go from the 1st line to the $start_line?

Comment: @Anfoni, Re "*Is there a way to jump directly to the start line without have to perform a getline for the first couple of thousand lines?*", Text files are not indexed, meaning there's no way to know where lines start. Even Tie::File needs to read all the lines up to the one you request. (Tie::File also takes 30x longer than not using Tie::File. NEVER use Tie::File)

Comment: @choroba, Tie::File gets very slow and memory hungry <del>when processing large files.</del><ins>period</ins>. It stores the index of every line encountered on top of the configurable-sized buffer, and it has insane computational overhead no matter what size the file is.

Comment: Could also do `for (1 .. $end_line) { my $line = $z->getline; next if $_ < $start_line; ... }`.

Comment: The first argument to seek is a number of bytes, not a number of lines.

Answer (score 3):

`Tie::File` is a bad idea for large files, as it needs to store the whole file in memory at once. It is also an impractical, if not impossible idea for compressed files. Instead, you will want to operate on an input stream of your data. And if you are going to modify the data, an output stream to a new copy of the data. Perl has pretty good support for gzip compression through the `PerlIO::gzip` layer, but you could also pipe data through one or two `gzip` processes.

```
# I/O stream initialization
use PerlIO::gzip;
open my $input, "<:gzip", "data.gz";
open my $output. ">:gzip", "data.new.gz";    # if $output is needed

# I/O stream initialization without PerlIO::gzip
open my $input, "gzip -d data.gz |";
open my $output, "| gzip -c > data.new.gz";
```

Once the input (and optional output) streams are set up, you can use Perl's I/O facilities on them just like any other file handles.

```
# copy first $startLine lines unedited
while (<$input>) {
    print $output $_;
    last if $. >= $startLine;
}

while (my $line = <$input>) {
    # blah blah blah
    # manipulate $line
    print $output $line;
    last if $. >= $endLine;
}

print $output <$input>; # write remaining input to output stream
close $input;
close $output;
```

Comment: Re "*Tie::File is a bad idea for large files, as it needs to store the whole file in memory at once*", That is not true. It only keeps a configurable-sized portion of the file in memory. But it does store the offset of every line it encounters in memory, and that can easily take as much memory than the file itself. So Tie::File isn't only insanely slower than the alternatives --I've seen it be 30x slower in my tests-- it also uses more memory than simply loading the entire file into memory. It's an awful module that should be avoided.

Answer (score 1):

You write: "*In my test case file I am interested in only reading in lines 123080 to 139361*".

This can be done in the shell as well:

```
zcat file | tail -n +123080 | head -16282
```

Or by:

```
my $file = 'the_file.gz';
my($from,$to) = (123080,139361);
my @lines = qx( zcat $file | tail -n +$from | head -@{[-$from+$to+1]});
```

This might be faster than a normal single core pure perl solution since the `zcat`, `tail` and `head` inside qx will become three processes, and perl is a fourth. And all four might get a separate cpu core on their own. You might want to test the speed with different line numbers.

Comment: Thanks for the tip! I'll definitely give it a try, and let you know the results!